# How to deploy Outlook Web Addin Manifest on IIS so that users can add via their My add-ins > Custom add-ins?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I have created an Outlook Web Add-in that runs great and all users can add it to their My add-ins > Custom add-ins from the Store icon on Outlook 365 when choosing to **Add from file**. However, when trying to load the same manifest from **Add from URL** Outlook is showing the following dialog.

[image: Outlook Installation failed]

I did download the validate-office-addin using npm. Here is the Validation "Passed" result:

[image: Manifest Validation Result]

All users who are trying to add the add-in from the URL have access to the web server and can browse the manifest file and see the XML Definition directly from a browser, such as Chrome.

Are there any steps that I am missing that should allow this to be available for adding the add-in from a URL?

Thanks

Comment: The Exchange Server(s) has to be able to browse to the URL.  Please check this.

Comment: Also in our Exchange 2016 on-prem environment, the Exchange Server is making the request to the manifest URL using an empty user-agent string, in case you have some module denying requests based on user-agent string.

Comment: Did you provide a URL that is only accessible from inside the company, and the the mailbox is in O365?  If so, this won't work with the URL option, because the Exchange Server where the mailbox is located will try to retrieve the manifest via the URL.  If the mailbox is on-prem then this may work, but not in general.  The next problem is whether the user can access where the office add-in is running from (e.g. the URLs defined within the manifest), after the manifest is installed.